# How to programmatically start conference call on iPhone

Tags: iphone

What are the ways to programmatically start a conference call on iPhone?

any knowledge about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of telling the iPhone to call someone is calling a "tel:0123456" url, the URL scheme for that is documented in the Apple SDK.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

If it is possible it is not documented, but I think not that it's possible.

Comment: thanks. don't they have a way to chain two or more numbers? as tel:0123456;099999;99993333  ??

Comment: Not as far as i know, you can test this if you type the url into the safari adress bar. If it works you'll see it.