# Call from a iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, call

Is it possible i can make a conference call from my ios application, CTCallcenter is able to do that or some other way, guide me, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Pls check [how to programaticaly start conference call on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396866/how-to-programaticaly-start-conference-call-on-iphone)